# Select fields list from entity using other type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I know that I can request a specific list of fields from the EF by using the anonymous type.

However. I need something else. I have a database model as well as a view model. view model - this is a simple DTO. There is no relationship between the models.
In the model from the database there are many heavy fields, I don't want them loaded, because they don't need me in view model.
I don't want to manually write the list of fields - there are many of them, and there are many models. And in the future, i will have to constantly remember and update this list manually.

Here is a sample code.

```cs
public class MyDbModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public byte[] Blob1 { get; set; }
        public byte[] Blob2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public List<MyViewModel> GetModels()
    {
        var myBooks = _dbContex.Books.Take(100).ToList();  // How can I restrict the list of loaded fields here using the MyViewModel type ?
        var myBooksVm = myBooks.ConvertToVm();
        return myBooksVm;
    }
```

Is it really necessary to use reflection for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution. In principle, this will suit me, but it will require significant improvement for myself.

The solution creates an anonymous type on the fly based on the passed list of fields. Then this object is passed to Select, which limits the list of requested fields.
https://byalexblog.net/entity-framework-dynamic-columns

Answer (score 0):

You could try lazy loading virtual properties.
Enable lazy Laoding in the EF Context and add Virtual keyword to the properties you dont want to load automatically

```
public class MyDbModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual byte[] Blob1 { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Blob2 { get; set; }
}
```

These virtual properties will  only be loaded when you access them

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also not an option. This will only work as long as the DB connection is open. I need to materialize the requested objects and return them from the method. Somewhere further after different logic, they will be converted to ViewModel. I would not want to keep an open connection to the DB all this way. In other words the method should return IEnumerable not IQueriable

Comment: Then I guess, you have to use Mappers
That's the only thing which fits your requirements

Comment: Mappers only converts one object to another. I'm interested in something else - I don't want to upload unnecessary heavy fields from the database.